# javafx tableview trigger action onfocus or onselect even if only 1 item is stored

Tags: events, javafx, tableview, selecteditem

So far I used the following event tableview.getSelectionModel().selectedItemProperty().addListener((observableValue, oldValue, newValue)

The problem is that if the tableview contains only 1 item the event is not triggered when the item is selected. Mouseevents are not a solution because the user might use the keyboard to navigate to the tableview, so i am looking for an onfocus or onselect event.

Thanks and br

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems as though you want to trigger your handler either if the selected item changes, or the table changes its focus state. You can do

```
    ChangeListener<Object> listener = (obs, oldValue, newValue) -> 
            System.out.println("Focus or selection changed");
    table.focusedProperty().addListener(listener);
    table.getSelectionModel().selectedItemProperty().addListener(listener);
```

Comment: Thanks, only one slight remark. I need to trigger the event only when the selection changes and the table gets the focus bot not when the tables loses the focus. Unfortunately I couldn't find distinct events.

Comment: You can't do `if (table.isFocused()) {...}` in the handler?